# AWS Athena: Error parsing field value and unexpected query results

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have the following table schema prepared by AWS glue

[image]

When I query the table using `SELECT * FROM "vietnam-property-develop"."sell" limit 10;`, it throws an error:

> HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '{"area":"85
>   m²","date":"14/01/2020","datetime":"2020-01-18
>   00:42:28.488576+00:00","address":"Quan Hoa - Cầu Giấy","price":"20
>   Tỷ","cat":"Bán nhà mặt
>   phố","lon":"105.7976502","avatar":"","id":"24169794","title":"Chính
>   chủ cần bán nhà mặt phố nguyễn văn huyên Quan Hoa Cầu Giấy, 2 tầng, dt
>   85m2. LH 0903233723","lat":"21.0376771","room":"0"}' for field 4:
>   org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Double

Then I tired to just query the title column by using `SELECT title FROM "vietnam-property-develop"."sell" limit 10;`

It returns result which I didn't expect. It seems that the query return the whole json files instead of just the title column. And the number of rows is 4 but not 10 no matter how I modify the query.

[image]